# Separador de milhar não está localizado corretamente no site principal

Tags: bug, status-intencional, layout

O separador de milhares está incorreto no site principal.

Por exemplo, na lista de usuários ordenados por reputação:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deveria ser 22,3 mil e 8.890, ao invés de como está na imagem. No meta estão corretas.

Além disso também está incorreto no site switcher e no perfil.

Comment: Isso aí indica o salário do usuário Math.

Comment: To ganhando tão pouco assim?  :(

Comment: E também está aparecendo "mil" em vez de "k". @renan Quem dera esse aí fosse o meu salário...

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, mas no principal está K. Estão invertidos em tudo na questão da localização. Na barra fixa lá em cima também um está com `.` e outro com `,`. E no site switcher também estão discordando.

Comment: Vou averiguar, mas não duvido que seja problema de caching

Comment: No meu entender, o de cima está tudo no padrão brasileiro/europeu (`4.482` e `29,5mil` ~= `29.500`) e o de baixo tudo no padrão americano (`22.3k` ~= `22,300` e `8,890`).

Comment: @mgibsonbr sim, você está correto, estava comentando isso nesse momento. Consertei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A localização de números *ainda* não foi ligada no site principal, só no Meta. A gente faz isso pra testar as coisas aos poucos, onde vai causar menos impacto.

Se tiver algum problema, avise aqui e a gente conserta. Se ninguém encontrar mais nada, ligamos no site principal hoje mais tarde.

Comment: faz sentido, por que a principio eu achava que o 29,5 mil deveria ser 29.5, mas aparentemente eu me cafundi :/

Comment: @Math Impressionante a velocidade com que eu esqueci completamente qual país usa `,` e qual usa `.` como separador decimal. Eu sabia até mudar pros EUA.

Comment: Eu também me confundo frequentemente, parece que esse é um detalhe fácil de esquecer.

Comment: @Math Eu culpo os EUA, que se recusam a deixar de ser bizarro quando o assunto é número, unidades e datas

Comment: Falou tudo!​​​​

Comment: Eu gosto do separador, mas prefiro `k` a `mil`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Já me debati quanto a isso. A decisão vai ser da comunidade.

Comment: @bfavaretto também estou com dúvida quanto a isso, estou mais acostumado com o "k", mas estou vendo o que acontece se eu tentar me acostumar com o "mil". No perfil pelo menos eu achei mais natural "~10mil pessoas alcançadas", mas para reputação o "k" parece mais legal.

Comment: Eu prefiro tb `k`, é mais "à programador", mas se fôr `mil` acho que deve ter espaço: `22.3 mil` em vez de `22.3mil`