# Separador de milhares, ora com ponto, ora com vírgula

Tags: bug, status-aceito, localização

Às vezes eu noto que há inconsistências nos separadores de milhares no site. Por exemplo, aqui no meta acabei de ver isso:

[image: 31.737 pontos de reputação e 2,144 perguntas]

Observe a inconsistência: Tenho 31.737 pontos de reputação (milhares separados com ".") e aqui há 2,144 perguntas (milhares separados com ",").

De vez em quando, a reputação fica com vírgula também:

[image: 31,737 pontos de reputação]

Acho que no caso da reputação, o número muda de separador quando a reputação muda por meio de ajax/websocket estando a página já carregada (muda de "." para ","). Entretanto, não tenho certeza acerca disso.

Nota: Isso não é uma duplicata [dessa outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3759/132).

---

## English translation:

Sometimes I notice there are inconsistencies in the thousands separators used in the site. For instance, I just saw this in Meta:

[image: 31.737 reputation points, and 2,144 questions]

Notice the inconsistency: I have 31.737 reputation points (the thousands are separated with a ".") and there are 2,144 questions here (the thousands separates with a ",").

Sometimes, reputation will get a comma separating it too, though:

[image: 31,737 reputation points]

I believe that in the case of reputation, the separator gets changed when the reputation is changed by means of ajax/websocket, the page not being reloaded (it changes from a "." to a ","). I'm not sure about that, though.

Note: This is not a duplicate of [this other question](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3759/132).

Comment: Para mim "." é consistente

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tenho uma aba que está aberta há algumas horas que está aparecendo com vírgula. Quando você carrega uma página qualquer, ela vem com ponto. Depois de um tempo (acho que quando a sua reputação muda) é que ela fica com vírgula.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é devido a tradução provavelmente, o outros sites usam `,`, só nós que fazemos moda :P, então as vezes dá este bug. Pessoalmente pra mim ficaria otimo se usasse tudo virgula mesmo e isso não fosse uma preocupação das páginas traduzidas.

Comment: Vi agora, numa aba abandonada que teve o escore atualizado, aconteceu exatamente. Depois da alteração do valor, na chamada ajax para preencher o novo valor de pontuação, o sistema faz bagunça

Comment: Para atualizar, semana passada eu consegui ver isso acontecendo exatamente no momento que o valor da minha reputação foi atualizado na barra superior do site.

Answer (score 5):

Quero ressaltar algo que eu já disse nos comentários, para mim esta internacionalização para o score/pontos é puramente perfumaria.

Ou seja muitos sites internacionais usados por brasileiros e portugueses usam o formato de virgula (`,`) para milhar e `k` para `1000`, então não tem porque internacionalizar aqui, as pessoas sabem a diferença e o que significa, tentar adaptar para `.` e `mil` é perfumaria e convenhamos, a adaptação/internacionalização não esta boa, ao menos pelo menos duas pessoas abriram perguntas a respeito disso, mostra que da forma que foi feita parece estranha.

Eu realmente acredito que deixar sem internacionalização já resolveria e todo mundo entenderia.

Acho que tinha que ser padronizado em todos sites **da REDE**, seja lá qual idioma usarem, todos países creio eu que já se acostumaram com `k` para se referir a mil.

Eu já desisti de certas discussões com *outros usuários*, *CMs* e do *meta.stackexchange.com* para expressar coisas do tipos, as pessoas querem perfumarias que de inicio parecem interessantes, mas na hora de por na pratica funciona parcialmente, que pra mim é o mesmo que não funcionar, esse caso da virgula e ponto é um claro caso de que funciona parcialmente. Fazer o simples já atenderia muito bem e se um dia criarem algo bem feito e bem testado para essa internacionalização do formato/abreviação de números longos ai sim colocaria.

Ainda sim é algo que me parece um baita exagero para os sites, creio que até sites grandes internacionais como facebook usem `k` para se referir a mil.

Se fossem valores monetários ai eu acharia totalmente justificável tal perfumaria, este é o tipo de situação que precisa mesmo deste tipo de cuidado, mas não é o caso, são apenas pontos/score, é muita preocupação por algo que não vai afetar em muita coisa usar o padrão que já usado nos demais sites.

---

Um exemplo de problema no site hoje:

> [image: bug da localização]

Isto ocorre porque simplesmente o sistema foi criado pensando no `k`, ai o layout bate de frente com um site que implementa um sistema de "localização" para converter com a suposta intenção de facilitar e acaba por quebrar, vejam que se estivesse com `k` ficaria normal:

> [image: se fosse com k]

Isso é porque o layout foi planejado com este limite mesmo, baseado no `k`.

Answer (score 4):

Só pra constar, carreguei a página e vi isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Daí fui ver nas ferramentas do navegador de onde vinham esses números. Não foram preenchidos em requisição Ajax. Já chegaram assim na resposta da requisição à página.

**edit: PEBKAC** <strike>Acredito que o erro é todo backend mesmo. Um dev deve ser capaz de resolver.</strike>

P.s.: não é só a gente que inventa moda, tem um SO em russo também, que também deveria usa vírgula ao invés de ponto. O SO em japonês e o original em inglês devem usar ponto como separador decimal. Já o SO em espanhol... Bem... [O mundo de língua hispânica é dividido nesse assunto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg).

Comment: Uma coisa é o 31,7 mil e outra é o 15.514. No primeiro, a vírgula é um separador decimal e não um separador de milhares.

Comment: Creio eu que o problema são as traduções, elas não estão presentes em todas páginas, tem muita coisa ainda pra resolver. Pessoalmente eu acho que esse de trocar virgula por ponto só por questão de localização é dispensável.

Comment: Em 31,7 a vírgula separa as unidades das casas decimais, ou seja está certo assim. O ponto em 15.514 tá separando os milhares das unidades, ou seja, tb está certo.

Comment: Obrigado por me chamarem a atenção. Eu teria fugido do MOBRAL, mas não precisei porque o programa já havia sido extinto quando eu cheguei na idade em que aprendemos nossos números XD Removi a alusão a erro na resposta.