# Ponto e vírgula na reputação

Tags: suporte

*Eu sei que é estranho perguntar isso, mas é uma coisa que é constante e infelizmente meu TOC me faz fazer essa pergunta.*

---

Intermitentemente, o "." (ponto) que separa os números da reputação, ele vira uma "," (vírgula) em algumas telas. Além disso, se atualizar a página, ela some, voltando ao ".".

[image: pontovirgula]

Como é algo que não influencia em nada, não caracteriza **bug**, mas para quem tem TOC é perceptível.

Seria uma atualização dos indicadores que provavelmente causam isso!?

Comment: Isso ja foi perguntado, se nao me engano.

Comment: Poxa, pelo menos não sou só eu que tenho TOC! rs

Comment: Quero ressaltar, mesmo que o pessoal não tenha dado bola para o que eu disse na outra pergunta, isso me parece um problema da tradução, no geral nas outras comunidades é usado virgula, isso de usar ponto é uma adaptação meio que feito como remendo aqui pro site SOpt, acho que simplesmente é algo dispensável, virgula para milhar esta bom demais, acho que tudo tinha que ser padronizado, todos países creio eu que já se acostumaram com `k` para se referir a `mil`. Mas também já desisti de certas discussões com outros usuários, CMs e meta.stackexchange.com, as pessoas querem firulas que...

Comment: ... mas na hora de por na pratica funciona parcialmente, que pra mim é o mesmo que não funcionar, sendo que o simples e padrão já atenderia muito bem e se um dia criarem algo bem feito ai sim colocaria, mas é perfumaria, é algo que realmente parece um baita exagero, creio que até no facebook usem `k` para `mil`... Afinal de contas os numeros aqui são score e não valores monetários para ter tanta preocupação assim e acabar colocando uma implementação mal feita.

Comment: Cara, não sabia que era "mais em baixo" o negócio. Agora entendi, mesmo que esse caso do ponto e vírgula é irrelevante, mas podem ter outros casos no mesmo contexto que não são tão irrelevantes quanto esse. Eu sinceramente não consigo imaginar como funciona o "relacionamento" do SE com o SOpt. Gostaria de saber mais sobre como funciona, se o SOpt é totalmente individual, onde fica o servidor, como é a estrutura de administração, etc... (não procurei por isso, ainda)

Comment: Converti os comentário em um resposta um pouco melhor explicada: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7202/3635 - sobre relação Stack Overflow (empresa) e SOpt não sou a pessoa certa para se falar, mas creio que a relação seja a mesma com qualquer site da rede, só o SOen tem um carinho mais especial, pois ele é o carro chefe da empresa :)