# Layout da home quebrado

Tags: bug

Não sei se foi só comigo, na home está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quem mandou ter + de 100 mil visitas? :D

Comment: Só um adendo... Essa quebra não acontece no Edge e no IE... Mas quem liga né? :p

Comment: Não testei no Edge @bio, mas é provavel que seja a renderização de fonte, talvez por 1px de diferença de a sorte de não quebrar o layout.

Answer (score 6):

> **Relacionado:** https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7202/3635

não é um bug necessariamente, **o layout foi feito pensado na "abreviação" com a letra `k`** e não com a palavra `mil`, o site pt-SO e ja-SO são os unicos que usam esquema de internacionalização (aparentemente)

Já os sites:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com
- https://es.stackoverflow.com

**Aparentemente** usam `k` para "milhar".

Ou seja, no pt-SO o `k` é uma letra e `mil` é 3, ou seja vai ocupar mais espaços.

E só pra constar creio que ainda tem parte do nosso site que usa o `k`, eu vou ser sincero, essa "internacionalização" deveria ser totalmente dispensável, se fossem valores monetários "localizados" teria sentido, mas não é, é apenas numeros, de score, de views e numeros de postagens, estou bem certo que todo mundo sabe que `k` é para abreviar mil, acho que seria muito mais sensato remover essa conversão/adaptação, que por sinal nem funciona tão bem, e simplesmente deixar como é em todos sites da rede.

Assim evintando problemas do tipo.

Comment: Unnn tinha visto sua resposta na outra pergunta, mas não tinha visto a [revisão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7202/4), essa pode ser fechada como dup até

Comment: @MarceloBoni acho que pode ser mantida em aberto pq a solução pode ser outro caminho, talvez trocarem o `float:left` por `display:inline-block` combinado com `white-space: nowrap;`, o que tecnicamente resolveria.